# Would it be risky to disable LMHash in GPO?

Tags: windows-server-2008, local-area-network

I run a AD server with Windows 2008, I have clients running XP and Windows 7, now I've decided to enforce Lan Manager authentication by refusing LM & NTLMv1 encryption methood, would it be risky? (I mean incompatibility)

And was LM hashes persistent or one-time storage? If it's persistent, would it be converted automatically (or with user interaction)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is pretty strangely worded, but it sounds like what you actually want to do is disable LM and NTLMv1. If this is the case, I'd say you're probably fine and that's a reasonable thing to do, leaving you with NTLMv2 and Kerberos.

NTLMv2 has been supported since NT4 SP2/2000.